# OS X: Watching for dialog box creation from an app

Tags: objective-c, events, macos, dialog, applescript

Is it possible to get OS X (Leopard or later) to notify you of dialog box creation?

I want to be able to watch for dialog boxes being created by a particular app and then do something depending on the dialog box that is displayed.  The "do something" will likely involve Applescript GUI scripting to click on buttons etc.

I have been told that Applescript does not provide notifications/events for window creation.  Is this possible with Objective-C or something else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Accessibility APIs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXModel/OSXAXmodel.html) can be used to do this sort of thing. There are a lot of APIs and the documentation can be a bit daunting, so a third-party developer has a framework called [PFEventTaps](http://pfiddlesoft.com/frameworks/) that purportedly simplifies writing "assistive applications".

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks.  I'm reading through the docs see see how to do the.  It seems like the "Notifications" are what I'm looking for, but I haven't found yet how to register for a "window created" notification.  Still reading...

Comment: I've edited my answer to also provide a link to a third-party framework called PFEventTaps. I've no affiliation with the author(s), and have not used this framework myself, but it purports to simplify exactly the sort of thing you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to have applescript event listeners to "listen" for a dialog. But I have written applescripts for indesign or quark that check for the existance of a dialog using a timeout and try statments to do what I want the dialog to do. But I would put code in to do that in areas of my script where I would anticipate the presence of a dialog

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I can't know up front when to expect a dialog.